# How to update JSON object using Yojson?

Tags: ocaml

After reading some examples, it's easy to construct a JSON object by `Yojson.Basic.from_string` or `from_channel`.

On the other side, we could also easily to convert a JSON object to string by `pretty_to_string`.

However, `update` an JSON object is tricky, for example the input parameter is as follows:

```
{
    "content": "test content",
    "base" : {
        "version": 1,
        "id" : "a001"
    }
}
```

I want to update the `"id"` in it and return a new JSON object:

```
{
    "content": "test content",
    "base" : {
        "version": 1,
        "id" : "a002"
    }
}
```

I tried to write a function to update a JSON object:

```
let update_json (js: json) (key: string) (new_value: string) : json =
  let rec aux (json_ele:json):json = 
    match json_ele with
    | `Bool b -> `Bool b
    | `Float f -> `Float f
    | `Int i -> `Int i
    | `List jl -> `List (List.map jl ~f:aux)
    | `Null -> `Null
    | `String st -> `String st
    | `Assoc kvlist -> 
        `Assoc (
        List.map
          kvlist
          ~f:(fun (okey, ovalue) -> 
              match ovalue with
              | `String v when okey = key -> (okey, `String new_value)
              | _ -> (okey, aux ovalue)))
  in
  aux js
```

I was wondering if writing a function as above is the best way to update a JSON object in Yojson?

Comment: For a more complete question, can you be more clear about "bugs"? Also recommend using the standard library instead of Core, so that your code doesn't have to be modified in order to try it.

Comment: you can simplify your code by handling `Bool, `Float f, ... with default (| _ as others -> others), and then just focus on `List and Àssoc that require each specific treatment.

Comment: I have a helper lib for thing as well, https://github.com/fxfactorial/podge/blob/master/lib/podge.ml#L227 you can take inspiration from that

Comment: There's an issue about this in the Yojson repo here: https://github.com/ocaml-community/yojson/issues/54/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what you mean by "bugs", but `` `Assoc `` doesn't take a `string * json`, it takes a `(string * json) list`. This means that in your `` `Assoc `` cases, you should do a `List.map`:

```
| `Assoc pairs ->
  List.map pairs ~f:(fun (okey, ovalue) ->
    if okey = key then
      key, new_value
    else
      okey, aux ovalue)
```

You may want to factor this function out and give it a name.